# New line character and <br> get rendered as rectangle box on Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, fonts, newline, microsoft-edge, webfonts

#### The Problem:

If your website use custom font for non-Latin languages (eg. Japanese, Chinese...) or use font icon, sometime the newlines (and `<br>` tags) will be rendered as a rectangle.

So on Chrome/Firefox it looks like this:

[image]

But on Edge it looks like this:

[image]

How do we solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because on Edge a space character (`0x20`) is rendered at new lines, and your font doesn't have a glyph for <s>Amerino</s> Latin space character.

[This is a known issue](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10160748/) (which is marked as resolved but apparently it's not)

---

**The simplest solution**, if your issue only occur with `<br>` tags, is to style `<br>` and make them use a default system font:

```
br {
  font-family: initial !important; /* Fix error on Edge (br render a Latin space character) */
}
```

---

If you are having issues with in-paragraph new line (e.g. `\n` character in an article), you're stuck with the lengthy solution of adding the white space glyph into your custom font.

You can use libraries like [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) to edit the original ttf/otf, adding in a `0x20` glyph, and after that it will work fine.

Comment: Good solution. It also provides easy "forwards compatibility", allowing you to easily make changes (if desired) when the "known issue" is resolved with some finality.